# How do i define a Datetime Range field in a custo form?

Tags: forms, datetime, drupal

I have enabled the module "Datetime Range" in Drupal core and are now trying to add such a field to a custom form. - But I simply cannot find out how..? I haven't been able to google the solution either!?

I managed to define a single datetime field using this code:

```
$form['field_time'] =  [
   '#type' => 'datetime',
   '#description' => $this->t('Enter datetime!'),
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/248624/how-to-use-daterange-field-programmatically). You can use this field when creating base field definition of your entity with your own module as stated in [docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/datetime-range/how-to-use-datetime-range-in-a-custom-entity). But when it comes to using form api, you have to provide two datetime elements.